Is the focus on monotheism by western philosophy due to cultural bias?
Western philosophy has a lot of argumentation regarding the existence of a God, almost exclusively monotheistic or with purely infinite attributes. There have been many books written about the conception of a God that happens to match up with the God of Western culture, whether it be the design argument or the doctrine of divine simplicity which primarily has Christian/Jewish roots or the ontological argument which argues that god is the greatest possible being and is transcendent, conceptions of which do not always hold in polytheism.
Is this due to cultural bias? Why would centuries of books just happen to make the same conclusions as the ancestors who didn’t ponder about the question as much?

We cannot, for example, attribute any thing infinite to God based on our observation and experience of finite effects. Nor can we attribute unity to the original cause of the universe on the basis of any analogy to human artifacts such as houses; as they are often built by a number of people working together. Perhaps, therefore, there is more than one God involved in the creation of the universe? More importantly, we are in no position to attribute perfection to God unless we observe perfection in his creation. Since there are evidently “many inexplicable difficulties in the works of nature” we are not justified in making any inference of this kind (Hume’s Dialoguee concerning Natural Religion, 5.6/166–7).


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The tradition of Western philosophy is nothing at all like the way you characterize it. The focus on monotheism is not universal, there have always been atheists, pantheists, and Manicheans among others. And for those who do focus on monotheism, this is not a mindless submission to culture, but is a result of a rich background of debate going back thousands of years.
Zoroastrianism was a monotheistic religion of Mesopotamia going back perhaps as much
as 4,000 years and is certainly no younger than about 1300 BC. In Egypt, they had a serious conflict between polytheism and monotheism about 1300 BC, although that instance and a lot of early monotheism was really monolatry, the belief in multiple gods, but believing that one particular god was vastly more powerful than the others, perhaps the creator of the word.
Greece was heavily influenced by both Mesopotamia and Egypt before the time of Socrates so it is perhaps not surprising that Socrates (470 – 399 BC) was sometimes taken as a monotheist. He is at least famous for an argument that piety cannot be justified by polytheism.
A couple of centuries after Socrates, Alexandria in Egypt was an extremely influential Greek colony and there were a lot of Jews there. Consequently, there was a great deal of debate over polytheism vs. monotheism. Also, the Jewish scriptures contain various religious arguments in favor of monotheism. These arguments mostly weren't the Greek kind, based on reason alone, but they were arguments, not just assumptions, and they openly acknowledged the alternative opinion.
In the Middle Ages both in Christian lands and Muslim lands there was a lot written arguing for monotheism. Monotheism was not just taken as the default; it was argued for. There was also a lot of argument over the aspects of God, including omnipotence, omniscience, and omnibenevolence, and whether God exists in time and space and whether he has any parts or is purely simple, whether he is a necessary being, etc. Christians mostly settled on standard answers to questions like these, but those answers were not just assumed. What you think of as mere cultural bias was developed over centuries of lively debate, and if non-philosophers today just assume the standard answers to many of those questions, that doesn't mean that philosophy does.
Even in the middle ages, there were people who argued against the Judeo-Christian God; some of them were persecuted by the Muslims and Catholics, but scholars were always willing to debate them. In the modern era, there has been an explosion of criticism of the Judeo-Christian God and whether we should accept the standard answers I referred to above. There was never a time when any set of beliefs about God were universal and beyond debate. You are improperly generalizing from your very limited exposure to these issues.
Furthermore, your reference to "the design argument" makes no sense at all. The design argument in its general form is nothing but an argument that the universe or life was designed rather than appearing by accident. It makes no assumptions about the designer or the number of designers and draws no conclusions about the designer(s) beyond the powers that the designer(s) would have had to have.

From https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/creationism/#IntDesTraCre:  "ID enthusiasts pretend to be neutral about the Intelligent Designer, but they clearly do not think that he or she is natural. No one pretends that the earth and its denizens are a lab experiment being run by a grad student on Andromeda."

@mudskipper God is an eternal child playing an eternal game in an eternal garden Aurobindo. This puts into flowery Victorian the Hindu mainstream notion of Krishna's lila. Mentioning this since (1) we dont need to go quite as far as Andromeda to get out of 'standard monotheisms' and of course (2) This place is hopelessly emically Christian at best etically and exotically everything else. I believe you know this distinction wrt Chinese philosophy

@mudskipper, well, I just lost some respect for SEP. That's clearly an ad hominem attack, not a philosophical argument. It's also false. ID proponents don't "pretend" anything. If you ask them what their beliefs are they are happy to tell you. Some of them describe their beliefs in their publications so that the reader can be aware of their potential biases because they feel that's the honest thing to do. They don't "pretend" anything, what they do is leave their personal and religious opinions out of their scholarly articles, a lesson that whoever wrote that article needs to learn.

@DavidGudeman You're incensed at SEP for being Christian-western slanted. (Here the Christian being standard western anti-Christian). Why don't you apply the same standard to your answer? The question clearly asks for directions to step outside of christian-western framing. Your answer basically says the frame is good enoigh

@Rushi, I have no idea where you got the idea that I even think SEP is Christian-western slanted much less that I'm incenses about  it. And no, the question does not clearly ask to step outside the Christian-western framing, and no, my answer does not basically the fame is good enough. You  seem to be reading an entirely different page than I am.

I'm not incensed by it compare with Just lost respect for it... ad hominem, not philosophy You're claiming these statements are compatible with each other?

@Rushi, do make an effort to read a little more carefully before you comment. I shouldn't have to tell you what I said because it's right there in my comment: I lost respect for SEP for making an ad hominem attack.

@DavidGudeman I think SEP articles don't usually claim to be neutral--they're always written by someone who is generally more sympathetic to one side than another, and frequently very argumentative. Though I agree that this one is fairly extreme and reads less like a philosophy overview than a rationalwiki rant
